# How to design parallel web api in c#?

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, .net-4.5

I am trying to design a web api that can get data from an external server but with limitations. I'm trying to figure out how best to design it to be efficient.

My api has an endpoint that takes an input. It is is a domain name like `tom@domain.com`. My endpoint then makes an http call to the domain to get an auth token, then makes another call to that domain with the username to get some data which is returned to the client. However my api can accept multiple usernames (comma delimited like `?users=tom@domain.a.com, bill@domain.b.com`). My web server knows for each domain what is the max parallel connections I can make to get the data.

So the problem is how to organize the data so I can maximize parallel computing but stay within the limits.

Here's my thoughts:

First parse the user list and group them up. Then have a static dictionary. Key is domain, value is a custom object which has 2 queues. Both queues holds a list of `Tasks` (from async/await). However the first queue max length will be the value of the limit for that domain.

```
?users=bill@D.com, max@D.com, sarah@A.com, tom@D.com

dictionary = {
    "D.com" : [
         [],
         ["bill@D.com", "max@D.com", "tom@D.com"]
     ],
     "A.com" : [
         [],
         ["sarah@A.com"]
     ]
}
```

Then I can run a code every second, which loops through all dictionary values, and fills the first queue with as many Task objects from the second queue (.e. removing from 2nd queue and putting in first) so its within the limit.

As soon as its in the first queue, the task executes using `Parallel.Invoke()` then when the task is completed it gets removed from first queue (unless some request is waiting for it, explained in next paragraph).

I do this because if another api request is made to my endpoint with some names thats already from the first request, I want to reuse it. So If it's in the first queue, I call `await` on that Task.

Somehow when a task finishes, I need to know that no other people are waiting for that user in the task, and in that case, remove it from the first queue. Also if a client disconnects it should remove the watching of the users part for that client.

Does anyone know if this is a good approach?

Comment: You lost me after three paragrpahs :) but http calls are naturally async  and IO bound so you can do many many calls simultaneously with async/await.

Comment: I could do that, but for domain `D`, it will return a bad request after I make `D'` concurrent http calls. I know what `D'` is based on the domain `D`, so I have to stay within that limit.

Comment: For example if the limit for domain D is 2, then doing `?users=bill@D.com, max@D.com, sarah@A.com, tom@D.com` will result in a bad request for tom.

Comment: OK, so your bottleneck is not the .net framework, but the services you are using. That is maybe more a question for the software engineering site than SO, which is help with code that isn't working.

Comment: But this is also about which are the recommended classes to use with .net 4.5

Comment: FWIW You might have to also consider the bottleneck of two API calls being made simultaneously which will also take you over the limit. You've probably already considered that, of course :)

Comment: But even if 5 users contact my endpoint, the code that checks the limit would run synchronously before the parallel stuff happens right?

Comment: Assuming that your queue is shared by all requests and you synchronise it correctly, then yeah you should be fine. I just wasn't sure from your question if your approach was for a shared queue, or a queue per request.

Comment: The main dictionary that has all the queues would be static so shared.

Answer (score 2):

Since it's parallel, you know right away you're probably going to need to use `System.Collections.Concurrent`, and since you need key/value lookup (user identifier/HTTP response) you need a ConcurrentDictionary. And since there is a common cache for all users, you will want to store it in a static variable, which is available to all threads and all HTTP requests.

Here is a simple example:

```
public class MyCacheClass
{
    //Store the list of users/requests
    static private ConcurrentDictionary<string, Task<HttpResponseMessage>> _cache = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, Task<HttpResponseMessage>>();

    //Get from the ConcurrentDictionary or add if it's not there
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetUser(string key)
    {
        return await _cache.GetOrAdd(key, GetResponse(key));
    }

    //You just to implement this method, potentially in a subclass, to get the data
    protected virtual async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetResponse(string key)
    {
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        var url = string.Format(@"http://www.google.com?q={0}", key);
        return await httpClient.GetAsync(url);
    }
}
```

Then to get a user's information, just call:

```
var o = new MyCacheClass();
var userInfo = await o.GetUser(userID);
```

Note: If you're going to use code like this on a production system, you might consider adding some means of purging or trimming the cache after a period of time or when it reaches a certain size. Otherwise your solution may not scale the way you need it to.

Comment: Whats the use of `concurrent` dictionary and `virtual`?

Comment: why can you remove that?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto True, you *could*. Although any exceptions might get raised in a place that wasn't expected, and any disposal calls would break everything (BTW oops I forgot to dispose my HttpClient).  See [this article](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html).